# Is it possible to execute arbitrary C# code when registering COM dll?

Tags: .net-core, com

I'm trying porting a C++-written [Windows IME sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/IME) into C#/.NET Core 3.

The C++ sample have a global DllRegisterServer function, which will be called by `regsvr32`:

```
STDAPI DllRegisterServer(void)
{
    if ((!RegisterServer()) || (!RegisterProfiles()) || (!RegisterCategories()))
    {
        DllUnregisterServer();
        return E_FAIL;
    }
    return S_OK;
}
```

Here, `RegisterServer()` is related with COM registration and the others registers the sample as an IME. The COM shim in .NET Core 3 [automatically does the former for me](https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/blob/master/Documentation/design-docs/COM-activation.md#net-core-class-com-activation), but I'm not sure how I can call others in C#.

Is it possible to execute arbitrary C# code when registering a dll by `regsvr32`, so that I can register my dll as an IME?

Comment: Are you looking for ComRegisterFunctionAttribute attribute: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.comregisterfunctionattribute?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @SimonMourier I think so, thanks! But I think it's never being called even when I added that attribute and use `regsvr32`. Registration itself goes well but nothing happens even when I do `Debug.Assert(false);`.

Comment: Oh, well, this is called only when using RegAsm I guess, not for .NET core...

Comment: comhost.dll source is here: https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/blob/4f7fefe81748bcf7fe65ad3492ed2ca22a2b834a/src/corehost/cli/comhost/comhost.cpp I don't see any way to add custom stuff in there (an equivalent of ComRegisterFunctionAttribute). Maybe you should file an issue to https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup

Comment: Brr, they made it awfully convoluted.  But you have a much bigger problem, an IME is going to inject the CLR into any process with a UI.  Including the ones that already use .NETCore.  The killer detail in the "Compatibility concerns" section is "There is no support for different versions of .NET Core running concurrently".  Fuggedaboudid.

Comment: Filed https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/6286. Thanks! BTW, I'm doing this for study so for now I'm less concerned about compatibility.